# emv Enciphered pin

Tags: c, apdu, emv

I am doing card holder verification using enciphered pin and sending the verify command to verify the enciphered pinblock but I am getting res 6700.

```
TP_ApduSendT apduSend;
TP_ApduRespT apduResp;
uint8 slotNo = 0;

apduSend.Command[0] = 0x00;
apduSend.Command[1] = 0x20;
apduSend.Command[2] = 0x00;
apduSend.Command[3] = 0x88;
apduSend.Lc = 128;
apduSend.Le = 0;
```

The enciphered data is 128 bytes.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your problem better, including the expected output and more details on the error.

Comment: This is what am doing, capture PIN entered in plaintext format i.e (1234), construct a pin block(0412AC89ABCDEF67) using the pin and the pan and iso format 0, concatinating (7F, pinblock, unpredictable number, random padding), applying rsa algorithm to obtain the Enciphered PIN Data(128 bytes), and then sending the verify command to ICC but when I put apduSend.Lc = 128; command is not sent and when I put apduSend.Lc = 0; I get wrong length 6700

Comment: @Meg, did you sent _GET CHALLENGE_ command before sending _Verify_ command? And what is the key size of ICC Private Key? Are you sure it is 128 byte? Moreover EMV verify command use ISO 9564 Format 2.

Comment: I sent GET CHALLENGE command and got a 8byte unpredictable number. The ICC public key modulus is 128 bytes.

Comment: I am sending a VERIFY command including the Enciphered PIN
Data which is this(82DC1467927A62EED292420528ADC07328D37D280930A0A7BA2C007254752837AB1D2EC3A2F828878ED37DABC3CBB619182FFD845DE6463FA9DEB9ADAD3F37BE072A5A3D737CC197B8CB7287853869D32C5288CD8B4B6C72C56A3D7CDC893660895ED72850CBD223B91E8DDFC8DA8DA9262DA51DA9728721C5437D0D8269013C) and setting apduSend.Command[0] = 0x00;
 apduSend.Command[1] = 0x20;
 apduSend.Command[2] = 0x00;
 apduSend.Command[3] = 0x88;
 apduSend.Lc = 256;

Comment: @rakeb,mazharul, I have used ISO 9564 to format the pin but am still getting 6700. The ICC public key modulus is 256 characters and the enciphered pin data is 256 characters so I put 128 in apduSend.Lc = 128.

Comment: @Meg, You sure the ICC supports Enciphered PIN verification? Maybe it only supports _plaintext_ PIN. Send this APDU Command and see what's the status word: `00 20 0080 08 241234FFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: I have read this from the card(8E 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 01 44 03 41 03 42 03 1E 03 1F 03 )
          Cardholder Verification Rule
            Rule: Enciphered PIN verification performed by ICC
            Condition Code: If terminal supports the CVM
            Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsuccessful
          Cardholder Verification Rule
            Rule: Plaintext PIN verification performed by ICC
            Condition Code: If terminal supports the CVM
            Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsuccessful

Comment: @rakeb,  
I have read this from the card(8E 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 01 44 03 41 03 42 03 1E 03 1F 03 ) Cardholder Verification Rule 1: Enciphered PIN verification performed by ICC. Condition Code: If terminal supports the CVM Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsuccessful Cardholder Verification Rule 2: Plaintext PIN verification performed by ICC. Condition Code: If terminal supports the CVM Apply succeeding CV Rule if this CVM is unsuccessful

Comment: @rakeb, if I put apduSend.Lc = 128; of which 128 is the actual length of hex values sent to the card as data in, command is not sent and if i put any other value eg 0, the command is sent and I get a response as 6700

Comment: @Meg, did you sent the command I posted earlier comment? Moreover can you show me the complete APDU command? I'm not sure whether `apduSend.Lc = 128;` is equivalent as `Lc = 0x80;`.

Comment: @rakeb, apduSend.Lc = 128; is equivalent to Lc = 0x80;

Comment: @rakeb
 apduSend.Command[0] = 0x00;
 apduSend.Command[1] = 0x20;
 apduSend.Command[2] = 0x00;
 apduSend.Command[3] = 0x88;
 apduSend.Lc = 0x80;

Comment: @rakeb, the command You sent earlier worked but it's for plain pin verification. I am doing enciphered pin where you have to concatenate (7F, pinblock, unpredictable number, random padding), apply rsa algorithm to obtain the Enciphered PIN Data, and then sending the verify command to ICC with the encrypted Enciphered PIN Data.

Comment: @rakeb, do you have an idea of how I can solve that problem? I am still stack

Comment: @Meg, can you provide more information? Like witch payment application are you dealing with (e.g AMEX, JCB, VISA etc)? Do you have their specification?

Comment: As @rakeb.mazharul says, the PIN block for PIN "1234" should be `241234FFFFFFFFFF`. Did you try this value (of course encrypted according to Book 2)?

Comment: @Meg, please ensure you put Enciphered PIN Block into the APDU Data as HEX, and not as String. Add your source part where you place Binary Enciphered PIN Block into APDU Data variable.

Comment: @rakeb, I tried it out with a different card and it worked and I got response  SW1 SW2: 67 C1(verify fail, 1 try left), tried with another card and  got SW1 SW2: 69 85(Conditions of use not satified)

Comment: @rakeb, it worked with a different card and responded with SW1 SW2 9000. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Meg, You are welcome. As I told you earlier most probably your card is not supporting Encipher PIN.